# Erode-like filter from Gimp in Photoshop

Tags: gimp, tools, filter, grayscale

I'm seeing a guy on YouTube making a heightmap for sand dunes, using Gimp and Photoshop.

In **Gimp > Filter > Generic** he has this tool called "Erode"

[image]

Which accomplishes the following

[image]

I played around a bit with Photoshop filters but didn't find it. Do you how I could achieve something similar?

Comment: Welcome, Link to video would help.

Comment: Ok, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpY504Zxy7c&t=92s --- it isn't in english though :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading of decription of erode in the gimp manual. Leads me to conclude that erode is just 1 px (square) **filter → other → maximum**. Looking at the video its either more likely minimum or he reverses the image after some applications of the effect.

But yes using maximum and then eventually reversing the image produces atleast mostly the same effect.

Comment: How so reversing the image? Ok, I played around with maximums and minimum, it does look more like his in the video, thank you :)